# Use Php gettext in Typescript

Tags: php, angular, typescript, gettext

I am interested in AngularJs 2, thus I intend to use it in my new project. However, I want to enable i18n with Php gettext.

I used Php gettext in my previous project, as follow (embed Php in javascript)

```
//saved as "js-functions.php"
var msg = '<?php echo _('Hello, I am newbie in programming'); ?>';
```

However, if I use Typescript, I don't know how to use "*include*" the Php tags in a Typescript file.

```
//saved as "app-template.ts"
let msg = '<?php echo _('How should I include this in .ts file?'); ?>';
```

Will it be a problem in transpiling the Typescript in Javascript? Or problematic for the intellisense?

**Related question:**

Besides, I have seen a few tutorial suggest that we should let the Angular Js 2 to handle all the view, and those data (include strings) should be sent from the server to make it RESTful. So, do I need to re-structure the program and try to translate those strings in server, and sent to the client for display?

Hmmmm... what if I have a `privacy-policy.ts` file, the file defines the `template`, and including the static content (i.e. bla bla bla, all those boring words), should I translate those words in server, and sent to the client for display? Is it the right practice to write all those words in Angular Js 2 `template`?

Hmmmm... or are they any **php gettext replacement** for Typescript, I am looking for a tools that can automatically grep all gettext strings from my project, including the Php, js and ts file.

Or if you have any better idea in handling i18n for a Typescript + Php project, may please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Answering a bit old question. Hopefully, will be useful to anyone who lands in here.

There are a couple of ways you could achieve this, but I'd suggest not to go down the path of embedding PHP tags in javascript variables.

You're on the right track where you could have one file that contains all the translations and it would export one function that would translate your strings to respective locales using that data. Those translation data could either be bundled together with your main javascript file and sent to the client or they could be extracted out to a separate file so that the browser can load data simultaneously and reducing your bundle size.

Or you could host an API that gives you the translation data based on the locale you're trying to convert to and injects it on your application.

Whichever paths you go, you can find a couple of i18n libraries in npm if you don't plan on doing so yourself.